# Setting to use git-bash as default shell when connecting remotely via OpenSSH to Windows Server 2016

Tags: ssh, powershell, openssh, windows-server-2016, git-bash

The [Powershell OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH) website has good instructions on how to install and use OpenSSH.

These include how to "Configuring the default ssh shell (optional)"

If I elect to use git-bash instead of powershell, what `-Value` do I put into the following other than `"/c"`

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShellCommandOption -Value "/c" -PropertyType String -Force
```

I get a blank screen when I set the default shell to be git-bash.
I tried `"-c"` and `"-l -i"` but neither one worked and I am still getting a blank screen.

Comment: Does the title bar show anything? When I open git-bash normally, flags `--login -i` are included. Does it work without a `DefaultShellCommandOption` set?

Comment: The title bar only shows which shell program I am using on the local computer.  When I set the default OpenSSH shell on the remote to be powershell, it works fine using either git-bash, powershell, or cmd on the local.  The problem happens when I choose to set the default OpenSSH shell on the remote to be git-bash.  The command prompt is blank regardless of using no `DefaultShellCommandOption` or setting it to `"-l -i"`, `"--login -i"`, or `"-c"`

Comment: I should also note that git-bash works just fine on the remote computer.

Answer (score 18):

This should be all you need:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" -PropertyType String -Force
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you explain it? :)

Comment: From here where they are setting the default shell to powershell, answer above just substitutes git bash for powershell https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/DefaultShell

Comment: `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe` also works for opening WSL bash on windows!

Comment: @RayFoss, C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe works only when you install a Linux distro on Windows. For me, it asked me to install a distro :)

Comment: @user2819573 Thanks for your answer, I was using the GUI version .exe file in "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe", as soon as I changed path to "C:\Program Files\Git\bin/bash.exe", it started working :)

Comment: `bash.exe` does not seem to run as a login shell, so it doesn't source `bash_profile` as I'd expect. Is there any way to use bash as a login shell for `ssh`? I tried adding `--login` to the registry value, as well as chaning it to `C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe`, but both of those exit immediately when I `ssh` in.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use the cygwin provided bash, this worked for me:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH]
"DefaultShell"="C:\\cygwin64\\Cygwin.bat"
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a file over "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git-bash.cmd" with:

```
@ECHO off

cmd /c "%ProgramFiles%\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login
```

then execute the following command on powershell

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git-bash.cmd" -PropertyType String -Force
```